# two network cards and a VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, routing

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here but I'm getting lost.

Our setup is very simple:
Three servers each with 2 NICs (a public and a LAN card for each, LANs connecting 2 both servers like this

158.xxx.xxx.xxx(wan1)<->10.14.18.11<--LAN-->10.14.18.12<->208.xxx.xxx.xxx(WAN2)<---IPSEC VPN--->207.xxx.xxx.xxx(WAN3)<->172.24.16.200

158.xxx.xxx.xxx is a Ubuntu 14 webserver
208.xxx.xxx.xxx is a Sophos UTM creating a IPsec VPN to 207.xxx.xxx.xxx

The VPN is up an traffic flow perfectly between the sophos and the far end 172.24.16.200. Even from this one it reaches the web server no problem.

The issue is that from the webserver we can not reach the far end 172.24.16.200

We have eliminated the VPN or sophos as being the issue and all point to a missing route when going tot he webserver to the far end

We tried adding a static route like this:

ip route add from 10.14.18.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.14.18.11 table rt2
ip route add default via 10.14.18.1 dev eth1 table rt2

ip rule add from 10.14.18.11/32 table rt2
ip rule add to 10.14.18.11/32 table rt2

but we get a RTNETLINK answers: File exists on the second command.

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a confusing situation. How can it be that you can communicate from one end to another, but not vice-versa, when we know the communication involves successfully sending two way traffic? But it is one that I spent a few hours helping another person on.

The answer to this is actually quite basic. The Sophos unit is NATting the traffic. When the traffic from the far end 172 VPN reaches your internal network the Sophos unit changes the source address to its own (10.14.18.12) for NAT. The web server receives the traffic, sourced from the Sophos and replies to the Sophos, which then unNATs the traffic and sends it back to the remote end of the tunnel. All is good.

However, when the web server tries to initiate a connection to the remote VPN tunnel endpoint (172) it doesn’t have a route to 172.x.x.x and sends the traffic out the default gateway (WAN).

The problem is two fold. The Sophos unit should NOT be NATing the traffic, between two private networks, in most use cases. And the systems on the 10.14 network have to have a route to the (172.x.x.x) network assigned statically (or via DHCP option 121 or 249).

In addition, the example you gave setting static routes does not look right. You used a previously unmentioned IP address of 10.14.18.1 as a gateway and makes no mention of the remote network you are trying to reach. The proper route command would be:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/12 via 10.14.18.12
```

NOTE: This command is only temporary.

So, turn off the NATing and specify a proper static route on the web server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. This was it! Now we have traffic flowing correctly via the VPN to the far end. =)